# Can I compare the cardinality of two uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have an infinite set, say $B=(0,1)$, and I have $A \subsetneqq B$, can I say $|A|<|B|$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality?

On one hand, for every element in $A$, we can find a corresponding element in $B$; but the inverse is not true. Thus, it seems to suggest that $|A|<|B|$.

On the other hand, it also seems that we cannot use such intuitive methods to compare the cardinality of these two sets because they are uncountable.

I hope someone can help me clarify my doubts. The reason I'm wondering this is that I hope to know whether I can write a rigorous mathematical expression to describe $A$ as the largest subset of $B$ that satisfies some constraints (let's just call the constraint $f(A)=c$ here) as the following

$$
A = \arg\max_{A\subset B, f(A)=c} |A|
$$

Comment: The same intuition is false for countable sets. I.e. though the primes are a subset of the integers, they have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Two sets have the same cardinality iff there is a bijection between them. Let $A=(0,1/2)\subsetneq B$. There is a bijection $$f:A\to B:x\mapsto 2x.$$

Even for countable set, this intuition is also false. Let $S$ be the set of all even integers. Then $S\subsetneq\mathbb{Z}$ but $|S|=|\mathbb{Z}|$ with the same map $n\mapsto 2n$.

That is also why infinite sets are more confusing that finite sets. In fact, some definition of infinite sets also says that

> A set $A$ is infinite if there is a **proper** subset $B$ of $A$ such that $|B|=|A|$.